# Code wont scan the words inside my array and only in quotations

Tags: discord, discord.js

Im trying to scan the inside of an embed like my last question i managed to fix the error but now the code just will not scan the inside of an array of words.
Code: https://pastebin.com/jeyaHKhK

```
-------------------------------
There is no error just the line 
if (message.embeds[0].description.includes("Enjoy the videos and music you love on YouTube.")){
-------------------------------
Will not scan inside an array and will only scan if it  has quotations like this ^
```

Comment: Reset your token if you haven't already. You've showed it in your pastebin

Comment: i had changed some of the letters to funny words dont worry

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't looping through the array, you are just looping for the amount of times the array is long. This should make it work by looking at your Pastebin:

```
if (message.embeds[j].description.includes("Enjoy the videos and music you love on YouTube.")){
```

Notice that I replaced the "0" from index with the "j" variable of the loop, which now means he cycles through all the items in the array.